# Color Swatch / Variant dropdown list for shopify products

Tags: shopify, variant

What I intend to do is to do a dropdown list for the product 'color' variant, however with some sort of association with the option value, an image swatch or jpg is displayed.

I found this tutorial to do association of color swatches with product color choice.
However, this displays variants in a button form instead of the defaul dropdown.

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/add-color-swatches-to-your-products

I've been messing about with the scripts but I never got around to getting what I needed.
so here I am for a little bit of help.

Here's my variant list:

```html
<select id="product-select-option-1" class="single-option-selector">
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="White">White</option>
  <option value="Black">Black</option>
</select>
```

generated by :

```asp
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}  
</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way for me to.. say, associate value="Red" with a 20x20 red square or say, red.jpg ?

Here's a screenshot for a better idea:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU7GF.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code from the Shopify article you linked to in your question ([Add color swatches to your products](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/add-color-swatches-to-your-products)) as a starting point and tweaked it to only display one square that changes color depending on the selected option.

Create a new snippet, **swatch.liquid** (this is a reduced version of [swatches.liquid](https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/3452112/raw/25e4d091da9e4a30a79d90a4a56dd230e708a252/gistfile1.html)):

```
<style>

/* Style the swatch */
.swatch { margin:15px 0; }
.swatch ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
.swatch li {
  /* Rounded corners */
  -webkit-border-radius:2px;
  -moz-border-radius:2px;
  border-radius:2px;
  /* Cross-browser inline-block */
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  /* Content must stretch all the way to borders */
  padding:0;
  /* Background color */
  background-color:#ddd;
  /* Spacing between buttons */
  margin:0px 5px 10px 0;
  /* Fake that those are buttons, i.e. clicky */
  cursor:pointer;
  /* The border when the button is not selected */
  border: #DDD 1px solid !important;
}

/* Styles for the text or color container within the swatch button */
.swatch li span { display:block; margin:5px 10px; }
/* Special styles for color swatches */
/* They don't contain text so they need to have a width and height */
.swatch li.color { width:50px; height:35px; }
/* The container of the image/color must be as big as its container */
.swatch li.color span { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; }

</style>

<div class="swatch clearfix">
  <ul>
    <li class="color">
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Include the swatch wherever you want it to be displayed in **product.liquid**:

```
{% include 'swatch' %}
```

Add something like this to the `selectCallback` function:

```
if (variant) {
  jQuery('.swatch li span').css("background-color", variant.option2); // or whichever option 'colour' is in your case...
}
```

You'll probably need to adjust that javascript depending on how you have your variants set up. For me, the colour is `option2`, which is then assigned to the `background-color` css property of the swatch.

Here's what it looks like in action:

[image: Color swatch gif]

It's a bit rough, but hopefully it will provide you with a starting point.

**Edit:** [gist available here](https://gist.github.com/stephsharp/7456d4f7386d5607b00f)