# Creating swatches in Shopify for a drop downlist

Tags: shopify

I try to create Swatches in Shopify for a drop down list. What I want, is the colour I'm selecting in the drop down, to appear underneath the drop down, on the right of it or somewhere in the page. I've read what some other answers but I can't figure how to change the background colour of the swatch based on the selection from the drop down list and if I need to create a new .css stylesheet just for the swatch.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017785/1367622).

This tutorial is a good starting point: [Adding color swatches to your products](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products)

To change the background colour of the swatch based on the dropdown selection, add something like this to the `selectCallback` function:

```
if (variant) {
  jQuery('.swatch li span').css("background-color", variant.option2); // or whichever option 'colour' is in your case...
}
```

**Edit:** [gist available here](https://gist.github.com/stephsharp/7456d4f7386d5607b00f)